# Merge nested objects in one list using Linq

Tags: linq

I have those two clases:

```
public class A
{
    public List<B> child { get; set; }
}

public class B
{ 
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

I want to get in just one List of objects from class "B",  which has the same name, so I did this:

```
IEnumerable<List<B>> result = manyA.Select<A, List<B>>(a => a.child.Where(b => b.Name == name).ToList());
```

But this is a List of List, and i would like to have just one list. Can I do this with Linq?

Comment: did you try SelectMany

Comment: Thanks! I missed that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
manyA.SelectMany(a => a.child)
     .Where(b => b.Name == name)
     .ToList();
```